# Flatten a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, flatten

I have a multidimensional array and want to break it down. Here's the array.

```
array
(
    [0] => array
    (
        [0] => array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [intsch_id] => 1
        )
        [1] => array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [intsch_id] => 2
        )
    )
)
```

And I want to break it down to

```
array (
    [0] => 1
    [intsch_id] => 1,
    [1] => 2
    [intsch_id] => 2
)
```

And this is in a dynamic query, so the results won't always be this simple. It will have the same structure as the above multidimensional array.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you simply want to remove the outer array? So something like `$new_array = $old_array[0];` ?

Comment: @user1199059: Your expected result is incorrectly written (it is visible thanks to the formatting I have done). Please correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the result array missing two commas?
One before each [intsch_id] key? 
Like this:

```
array ( [0] => 1, [intsch_id] => 1, [1] => 2, [intsch_id] => 2)
```

If so, it won't be possible to have multiple array values with identical keys, [intsch_id].

However, you just want to collapse the outer array that's holding this data, that's pretty straightforward:

```
$source_array = array(
    array(
        array(
            "0" => 1,
            "intsch_id" => 1
        ),
        array(
            "0" => 2,
            "intsch_id" => 2
        )
    )
);
echo '<pre>'; print_r($source_array); echo '</pre>';
$return_array = $source_array[0];
echo '<pre>'; print_r($return_array); echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will flatten your array structure:

```
function flatten_array($arr) {
  if (!is_array($arr)) return false;
  $ret = array();
  foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
    if (is_array($val)) {
      $ret = array_merge($ret, flatten_array($val));
    } else {
      $ret[$key] = $value;
    }
  }
  return $ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the fastest way:

```
function array_flat(&$ar) {
    function flat($item, $key, $res)
    {
        $res[$key] = $item;
    }
    $res = array();
    array_walk_recursive($ar, 'flat', &$res);
    return $res;
}

$sweet = array('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana');
$fruits = array('sweet' => $sweet, 'sour' => 'lemon');

print_r(array_flat($fruits));
```